# Email (imap) program on Ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, email-client

Is there a way to connect to email accounts using imap on Ubuntu Touch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the mail client Dekko. It is still in beta but it can do everything I want :)
It can connect to imap mail accounts.

It is available in the Ubuntu Store.

Please be aware that it does not use the accounts that are set up on the device yet.
That means if you want to connect to a googlemail adress you will have to enter username and password and enable [less-secure-access](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) for your Google account.